# How to check whether a folder is a shortcut or not using python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, file-io

I am making a simple program using python which takes two inputs from the user:-
filename which is the name of the file which the user wants to search.
pathname which is the path where the user wants to search the file.
I am using os module in my code.
But, I want that my program should not search for the file in shortcuts. So, is there a way by which we can check whether a folder is shortcut or not?
I am posting the definition of my function below :

```
def searchwithex(path, filen):
    global globalFileVal
    global globalFileList
    global count
    dirCounter = checkdir(path)  # checks whether the path is accesible or not.
    if dirCounter == True:
        topList = listdir(path)
        for items in topList:
            count += 1
            if filen == items:
                globalFileVal = path +'/' + items
                globalFileList.append(globalFileVal)
            items = path +  '/' + items
            if os.path.isdir(items): # checks whether the given element is a #file or a directory.
                counter = searchwithex(items, filen)
```

Comment: Related: [Check if file is symlink in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068419/check-if-file-is-symlink-in-python)

Comment: a) What is a shortcut? A link? A symbolic link? and b) Which OS are you working on?

Comment: @Ashwini: On Windows `os.path.islink()` returns `False` when given a path to a shortcut (a .lnk file) to a folder.

Comment: in Windows, a shortcut is indeed a file, right? So you need to check the content, no?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary symlink is not the same as shortcut, i tried the solution given in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068419/check-if-file-is-symlink-in-python)

Comment: @Hyperboreus I am working on ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Suppose, I have a folder A containing shortcut to A and some other files then my above function definitions keeps on running endlessly, because it again and again opens folder A on seeing the shortcut to A.I need to eliminate this problem.

Comment: @Pratik: To prevent loops you'll need to keep track of what paths you've already visited to avoid following them again. You could do this by keeping track of them all in a `set` and checking it before following any subdirectories encountered.

Comment: @justhalf: On Windows it's a file, but I'm not sure of the format (which is not plain text). But that doesn't matter because the OP's using ubuntu, so must be talking about a link.

Comment: @martineau I tried your solution. but its not working because OS treats the shortcut itself as a direct0ry. What I mean is that it shows the path as /A/A/A and so on which depends on how many time you opened the directory.

Comment: I still don't undestand what a shortcut is, especially under ubuntu.

Comment: [Possibly relevant.](http://www.howtogeek.com/106470/create-desktop-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-11.04-and-11.10/) AskUbuntu might have people with more knowledge of the subject.

Comment: @Pratik: Try storing the [`os.path.abspath()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=abspath#os.path.abspath) of each subdirectory in the `set` (and be sure to converting to that before checking to see if you've already seen one).

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I think they're symbolic links because I read where you can create them on ubuntu manually using the `ln -s ...` command.

Comment: Here is what I mean by a shrortcut <img src = "http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=658&tbm=isch&tbnid=Rsi8KRVKbcSDbM:&imgrefurl=http://www.technohunk.com/2013/08/how-to-make-custom-desktop-shortcut-with-custom-icon-ubuntu/&docid=ZmzNfj54zChYQM&imgurl=http://www.technohunk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ubuntuDesktopShortcut.png&w=237&h=198&ei=xD05UujfC8yXrAfCh4CgCg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:22,s:0,i:150&iact=rc&page=2&tbnh=158&tbnw=189&start=11&ndsp=16&tx=42&ty=82">

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, links (shortcuts) have a file type `".lnk"` so you could try `fn.endswith(".lnk")` which will return `True` for these shortcut files.  At least on Windows, `os.path.islink()` just sees a file, unlike on some other OS such as linux which has true links.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for (symbolic) links, please see if `os.path.islink` suites your needs.

```
$ touch a
$ ln -s a b
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os.path as _
>>> _.islink ('a')
False
>>> _.islink ('b')
True
```

I just created a Desktop "shortcut" graphically with nautilus, right clicking folder, chosing "create link" and it just creates a sym link. The above script identifies it correctly as a link.

Comment: its not working , symlinks and shortcuts are different. I tested the code on a shortcut and its not working.

Comment: Could you please explain what a "short cut" is?

Comment: Here is what I mean by a shortcut [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/106470/create-desktop-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-11.04-and-11.10/)

Comment: Thank you for the link and please see the edit to my answer. Please post a `ls -l` over a folder containing "shortcuts" and please post the result of `os.path.islink` for each of them.

Comment: What do you mean by placing a    ls -l over a folder?

Comment: Open a shell, navigate to the folder and then type in `ls -l`.

Comment: What does `ls -l` output? What does `os.path.islink` yield for the same item?

Answer (score 0):

It more comment, but for comments not work formatting. I don't understand what mean `shorcut` but I have hope, below will useful:

```
In [1]: import os
In [2]: files = os.listdir("./tmp/11");
In [3]: print files
['mylog', 'testfile1', 'test.py', 'testfile0', 'test.sh', 'myflags', 'testfile2']
In [4]: True if "test.py" in files else False
True
```