# python how to skip symlinks when checking folders

Tags: python

I made a script with python that creates placeholders in all empty directories so that they wont get deleted.

The problem with that is: it detects symlinks which I do not want to happen.

and I am getting error like: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'system/d/'`

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, glob

dirs = []
paths = ["system", "vendor"]
for path in paths:
    dirs.append(glob.glob(path + '/**/', recursive=True))

for dir in dirs:
    for dir1 in dir:
        if len(os.listdir(dir1)) == 0:
            open(dir1, '.PLACEHOLDER').close()
        else: continue
```

How do i ignore symlinks

Comment: try to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068419/check-if-file-is-symlink-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.walk` instead of glob, as in:

```
dirs.append(list(os.walk(path, followlinks=False)))
```

( Please note that according [to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), the default for `followLinks` is False - so you can omit this argument. )